# How to interpret contig-alignment.psa produced by velvet

Tags: read-mapping, rna-alignment

I'm using velvet to align given reads of RNA to given CDSs (i.e. coding areas and genes) of an organism, so I can generate gene-expression profiles. But after using `velvetg out-dir/ -alignment yes`, velvet produces `contig-alignment.psa` which is a file in a strange format. 
The file for every contig contains zero or more records of 7 integers, and I cannot understand their meaning.

The following is an excerpt of the file, and you can see the entire file [here](https://paste.ofcode.org/d9599cGH3aXnbdGqtWqrMs):

```
>contig_1
1    193    1939    1939    6   194 2
195 244 1   1   6   22  71
>contig_2
1   84  1   1   6   59  142
86  170 1935    1935    6   22  106
172 285 1935    1935    6   108 221
>contig_3
1   98  2   2   6   1   98
100 321 2   2   6   100 321
334 415 1204    1204    6   1   82
>contig_15
1   23  3   3   6   84  106
```

Comment: Is that the only file produced? The [.psa format](http://web.expasy.org/pftools/psa.5.html) is not like what you show (I think, anyway, I haven't used it before but that's what I could find). Are there really no other output files? If not, it sounds as though that might be a bug.

Comment: Of course there are other files that also appear while using velvet without the option `-alignment yes`. But related to contig alignment I can only see this file

Comment: I don't think velvet is doing what you think it is. Velvet is a genome assembler. To quote the velvetg command help: "-alignments <yes|no> : export a summary of contig alignment to the reference sequences (default: no)" If you want to align RNA-seq reads to a transcriptome and get "gene-expression profiles" use a tool such as bowtie2 or Salmon.

Comment: Thank you, I used Last aligner, but the reason I wanted to use velvet was because It generates coverage ratio that could indirectly imply gene expression.

Comment: @hhoomn It does in a very roundabout way and it won't give any measure of relative expression between genes. I think you need to explain what exactly it is you want to do in terms of a biological question. It seems to me you're asking the wrong question, here.

Comment: The question is that what does this file contain, and the answer is yet unclear, but I solved what I needed to do with another tool, if you want to know what I was doing see [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/how-can-i-compute-gene-expression-for-a-set-of-rna-reads)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to do a transcript isoform expression analysis. Velvet is a genome assembler, and really not designed for this task. The tools you are looking for are kallisto and salmon.